# How to serve static file in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a google verification file that I need to have in my root directory. How do I serve it and set up the route correctly in my app.py file? I thought just having it in the static directory would do the trick.

In my app.py file:

```
import requests; requests = requests.session()
from flask import (
    Flask,
    g,
    session,
    request,
    render_template,
    abort,
    json,
    jsonify,
    make_response
)
from jinja2 import TemplateNotFound

app = Flask(__name__)
```

...

```
@app.route('/ping')
def ping():
    return "OK"

"""
Catch-All Route
first looks for templates in /templates/pages
then looks in /templates
finally renders 404.html with 404 status
"""
@app.route('/', defaults={'path': 'index'})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def show_page(path):


    if session.get('tracking_url'):
        session['session_url'] = False
    templates = [t.format(path=path) for t in 'pages/{path}.html', '{path}.html']

    g.path = path

    try:
        return render_template(templates, **site_variables(path))
    except TemplateNotFound:
        return render_template('404.html', **site_variables(path)), 404

application = app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

I've tried adding this but it didn't work:

```
@app.route('/myfile.html')
def myfile():
    return send_from_directory('/static', 'myfile.html')
```

Comment: You are only serving items from your **template** directory; if Google looks for the static file in the root then it won't find items in the `/static` route however.

Comment: you are effectively preventing any `static` files to be found.

Comment: @njzk2: Werkzeug is pretty good at sorting routes and `/static/...` will be checked before this catch-all route.

Comment: When I place the file in templates it doesn't find it. How can I have a route to myfile.html that's stored in the static directory work without changing the catch-all route?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: thanks for the precision. I would have though otherwise. (no way to prevent statics from being rendered, then?)

Comment: @njzk2: Nope, but you won't find them in the *root* of the site, you'd look at `/static/filename` instead.

Answer (score 1):

For a one-off file that Google looks for in the root, I'd just add a specific route:

```
 from flask import send_from_directory


 @app.route('/foobar_baz')
 def google_check():
     return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, 'foobar_baz')
```

You are free to add in test in `show_page(path)` to try and serve `path` with [`send_from_directory()`](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#flask.send_from_directory) before you test for a template, of course; the second `filename` argument can take relative paths.